# Use tablename in subquery which has no mapped entity class in HQL

Tags: grails, hql

```
from Article as a where communityId=any(select communityId from tblcommunity where district_id=510185)
```

"tblcommunity" is a table in my database, I am using Grails 2.2.1, and exception message is :

```
tblcommunity is not mapped [from com.sccn.article.Article as a where communityId=any(select communityId from tblcommunity where district_id=510185)]
```

I want to know how to use tablename in subquery which has no mapped entity class in HQL.

Comment: If you don't want to map that table, you need to use direct sql.

Answer (score 0):

create in native query (`createNativeQuery()` or `createSQLQuery()`) :

```
select communityId from tblcommunity where district_id=510185
```

and then use the result as your hql param

```
where communityId in (:yourParamAsArray)
```

or for single result :

```
where communityId = (:yourParam)
```